# get all child terms

Tags: list, web-part, term-store

I want to get all terms including child. Currently have 3 Levels but it may increase so cannot hard code. Here is code which just give me parent terms.

```
string spWebUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(spWebUrl))
        {
           TaxonomySession taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(site);

           //get the default one
            TermStore termStore = taxonomySession.TermStores["OrganisationChart"];
           /* or you can get the one you want by looping through all the term stores
             taxonomySession.TermStores
           */

           var group = termStore.Groups["MyGroup"];

           TermSet termSet = group.TermSets["MyTermSet"];


            TermCollection terms = termSet.Terms;

            foreach (var t in terms)
            {
                Console.Write(t.Name);

            }

        }
```

Is it also possible to store this information in list on fly?

**Update1**
I dont need flat list by using `GetAllTerms`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just a flat list of all terms inside a TermSet you can use `GetAllTerms()` method.

```
TermCollection terms = termSet.GetAllTerms();

foreach (var t in terms)
{
    Console.Write(t.Name);

}
```

EDIT: If you want to preserve the hierarchy , you have to loop through each term as below:

```
TermSet termSet = group.TermSets["MyTermSet"];
TermCollection terms = termSet.Terms;
foreach (var t in terms)
{
   GetChildTerms(t);
}
```

Method implemented as below:

```
public void GetChildTerms(Term parentTerm)
{
    Console.Write(parentTerm.Name);

    if (parentTerm.TermsCount>0)
    {
       foreach (var t in parentTerm.Terms)
       {
           GetChildTerms(t);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont need flat list. I am very much aware about getallterms

Comment: also updated question

Comment: how to search specific term set from Group?